# C# Development State

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am not sure if it is possible, but is there a way in C# to differentiate when you are developing and testing vs the web site is already in production?

Clarification: Basically I am building a website and I want to be able to say

```
if(developing or testing mode)
    do this
else if(in production)
    do this
```

I have not started coding so there is no code available, but I am wondering if this is possible in c#?

Thank you

Comment: I'd be terrified of getting into a situation where it works in debug, and fails in production and its impossible to figure out why.

Comment: @asawyer luckily once can vary the debug conditional symbol independently from the other debugging related settings. Still I only use debug conditionals only for side effect free consistency checks in situations where the performance loss due to these checks is significant.

Answer (score 4):

[#if DEBUG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx)

Comment: And how do you close it? like you know, when you have #region blah, you close it with #endregion...is there something like this for it

Comment: At the link you can see the syntax.  #if DEBUG ... #endif

Answer (score 1):

If you want different code to actually be built for different environments, you could check out the [#if Preprocessor Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

If you're simply trying to make your program behave differently (but compile in the same code) then you could simply add a setting to the app.config/web.config file of your application:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="environment" value="production" />
</appSettings>
```

And then you can read it back:

```
if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["environment"] != "production")
    // do this
else
    // do this
```